# Git - Creating a PR shows older commits

Tags: git, github

Hello I am creating a PR from github to merge a branch called master_wes into master. When I compare changes, it is showing changes from all the previous commits that were merged in older PRs, instead of just showing the changes that have been made since the most recently merged PR.

This despite the fact that the only differences from the master and my local branch are the changes made since the most recent PR.

I've been re-using the same branch for all my PRs.

Here are my questions:
1) How to resolve this so that it only shows the commits since the last PR merge (done from master_wes)?
2) How to prevent this from happening in the future?

Thanks!

Edit:
Past PR merges from master_wes were done using squashed merges

Comment: Are you merging using squash merges or merge commits?

Comment: Squash I believe

Comment: Reusing a branch, eh? After each PR on your branch is merged into master, are you remembering to pull master and merge master into your branch? I sometimes forget to do that when I'm reusing a branch, and what you are describing is just what happens. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bad idea to use squash merges when merging two long-running branches.

When you open a pull request, GitHub shows the changes in your branch from the merge base (which is usually the common ancestor) between your branch and the base branch (the branch you're requesting to merge into).  If you use normal merge commits, that will usually be the most recent merge commit that's on both branches.

However, when you create a squash merge, you take your code and apply it as a single commit without using a merge commit.  Git has no knowledge that the old versions of your branch have been applied to `master` because there's no new shared history between them.  So when GitHub goes to compute the most recent common ancestor to show between your branch and `master`, it's the same as it's always been (which is the point at which your branch was originally created), and it shows all of the commits that have ever existed on your branch.

The easiest way to solve this is by using a new topic branch for each item you want to merge.  The second easiest way is to recreate the branch from `master` each time by using `git checkout -B master_wes master`, which will reset the branch to be the same as `master` (and destroy any changes on it).  You may need to force push your branch if you do the latter unless you deleted the branch on the server when you merged.

You can also avoid using squash merges (which I strongly recommend anyway), which will solve your UI problem, but continuing to merge the same reused branch again and again without resetting it tends to make the history a little gnarly (and cause certain operations to be needlessly slow), so I don't recommend doing that.